# Getting Facebook link from email on android

Tags: android, facebook

How do I get the facebook-link of an user when only having his email-address on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/). This is probably your best way of getting a facebook user from an e-mail address. Something like:

```
select user where email = email_address
```

Comment: Ive tried "http://www.facebook.com/fql?q=select user where email=jkallup@web.de", but i dont get any results there.

Comment: +1 to Kurtis for this info @Michael I think the Link says to use https://graph.facebook.com/+"your query"... and also instead of email there is also one "contact-email"

Comment: To better understand what im trying to do see this query: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6559846/gasg.PNG . I dont know if owner.email is possible in that way.. Else there would stand user={user id}. So i need to get the user id of the guy, that has an email of, for example, jkallup@web.de. Do i need to do that in 2 statements or can i merge them to one? Whats the easiest way to solve this problem?